# Paragraphs item doesn't load on node/add

Tags: 7

I have one content type were I cannot add Paragraph items.  I select the item, And I get the table header, but no paragraph loads, no error.

In logs I see:

> Location: .../system/ajax/
>
> Referrer: .../node/add/product/
>
> Message:
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #bundle in
>   theme_paragraphs_field_multiple_value_form() (line 1170 of
>   .../sites/all/modules/contrib/paragraphs/paragraphs.module).

Line 1170 is:

```
// Add the items as table rows.
foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
  $item['_weight']['#attributes']['class'] = array($order_class);
  $delta_element = drupal_render($item['_weight']);
  $cells = array(
    array('data' => '', 'class' => array('field-multiple-drag')),
    drupal_render($item),
    array('data' => $delta_element, 'class' => array('delta-order')),
  );
  $rows[] = array(
    'data' => $cells,
    'class' => array('draggable', drupal_html_class('paragraphs_item_type_' . $item['#bundle'])), // Line 1170
  );
}
```

This has worked, and I have other content types on which this field works.  I can not see any difference in the field or content types.

Has anyone run into this before?  I would love some direction on where to look for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it can be related to the [Entityqueue](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityqueue) module. The Draggable tables widget provided by the Entityqueue module doesn't take into account that their are other entity forms (like paragraphs in your case).

There is a patch to fix this currently but it needs some work: https://www.drupal.org/node/2460503

Comment: I used your solution to replace the Draggable Table widget on the Entity reference field that references the Entityqueue with a widget created by the Multiple Select module.  [link]https://www.drupal.org/project/multiple_selects[/link]